# Moving return statement to the right place

Tags: java, return

The  following java code works well and gives required output when written under the 'public static void main(String[] args)' as:

```
import com.google.common.collect.ObjectArrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class ArrayReturnSurTime {

public static void main( String[] args )
{ 

     int count1=0;
     int count2=0;
     int total_full_sur=0;
     float word_time= 0.25f;
     float full_sur_time=0.0f;
     float kan_sur_time=0.0f;
     float kun_sur_time=0.0f;

String word="srg]mp";
String modifyword=null;
String after =null;
String rl=null;

char[] c = word.toCharArray();
int m=c.length;
for(int i= 0; i<c.length; i++){
   count1++;

   if(c[i]==']'){count2++;}


 total_full_sur= count1-2*count2;

   full_sur_time=word_time/total_full_sur;
   kan_sur_time = (float) (full_sur_time*0.1);
   kun_sur_time = (float) (full_sur_time*0.9);
}
for(int i=0; i<word.length(); i++){  
char  a =  word.charAt(i);

if( Character.toString(a).equals("]")){
    int j = i-1;
    int k = i+1;
    char b =   word.charAt(j);
    char d =   word.charAt(k);
    modifyword= word.replace( Character.valueOf(b).toString(), ".");
    after=  modifyword.replace( Character.valueOf(d).toString(), ",");

    rl = after;

    String [] sur= word.split("(?!^)");
    String[] tmp_rl= rl.split ("(?!^)");
    float[] rlg_time= new float[sur.length];

         for(int x=0; x<rl.length(); x++){

        switch (tmp_rl[x]) {
            case ".":
                rlg_time[x]=kan_sur_time;
                break;
            case ",":
                rlg_time[x]=kun_sur_time;
                break;
            case "]":
                rlg_time[x]=(float)0.001;
                break;
            default:
                rlg_time[x]=full_sur_time;
                break;
        }

    System.out.print(rlg_time[x]+" ");

 }

}}}
}
```

It prints the float values as:

```
0.0625 0.0625 0.00625 0.001 0.05625 0.0625
```

I reshaped the program by covering the code(with minute need change )  in a method 'ranisurtime(String sur36)' to return the 'float[] rlg_time' to get the same output as:

```
import com.google.common.collect.ObjectArrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;
import java.util.regex.*;


public class ArrayReturnSurTime {

public static float[] ranisurtime(String sur36) { 


int count1=0;
int count2=0;
int total_full_sur=0;
float word_time= 0.25f;
float full_sur_time=0.0f;
float kan_sur_time=0.0f;
float kun_sur_time=0.0f;

String word=sur36; 
String modifyword=null;String after =null;String rl=null;

char[] c = word.toCharArray();
int m=c.length; 
for(int i= 0; i<c.length; i++){
   count1++; 
   if(c[i]==']'){count2++;} 
 total_full_sur= count1-2*count2; 
   full_sur_time=word_time/total_full_sur;
   kan_sur_time = (float) (full_sur_time*0.1);
   kun_sur_time = (float) (full_sur_time*0.9);
}
for(int p=0; p<word.length(); p++){  
char  a =  word.charAt(p);
if( Character.toString(a).equals("]")) {
    int j = p-1;int k = p+1;char b =   word.charAt(j);char d =   word.charAt(k);
    modifyword= word.replace( Character.valueOf(b).toString(), ".");
    after=  modifyword.replace( Character.valueOf(d).toString(), ",");

    rl = after;

String[] tmp_rl= rl.split ("(?!^)");
float[] rlg_time= new float[tmp_rl.length];

         for(int x=0; x<rl.length(); x++){

        switch (tmp_rl[x]) {
            case ".":
                rlg_time[x]=kan_sur_time;
                break;  
            case ",":
                rlg_time[x]=kun_sur_time;
                break;
            case "]":
                rlg_time[x]=(float)0.001;
                break;
            default:
                rlg_time[x]=full_sur_time;
                break;
        }

         }
         return rlg_time; //This 'rlg_time' is not being returned. Compiler ask return statement although this is the return statement,
}//First closing bracket to be crossed by 'return rlg_time'.
} // Second  closing bracket to be crossed by  'return rlg_time'.
             //return null;//It is the right place at which 'return rlg_time'. statement can do right, but how to manipulate to omit the above two closing brackets reach here.
}  

public static void main( String[] args )
{ 

   String sur36="srg]mp";

float[] A  =    ranisurtime(sur36);

for(int i=0; i<A.length; i++){
  System.out.print(A[i]);
}
}
}
```

But I failed. I know that 'return rlg_time'  is not at the right place (It should move two closing brackets ie '}' if it is to be returned, but being new to programming and java, nothing is comming in my mind to accomplish it. I need help to overcome this situatiion.

Comment: Ever tried to write correctly formated code?

Comment: Break out from the loop and return the value.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @ceving is right. Indent your code properly and it'll probably be a lot clearer where everything should go.

Comment: Is it certain that the strings to be processed contain only a single ']', which is neither the first nor the last characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The only reason that it is not working because you have declared and
>   defined your `rlg_time` within the body of an if-statement! And what
>   you are trying to achieve is to return this variable as a result at
>   the end of the method!!!

```
But, mind you, that the variables are local as per the blocks! Hence, your rlg_time is not returning the proper result.
```

To overcome this, you initialise your `rlg_time` alongside with other variables on the beginning of method. Use a local variable to use your temporary value,say `local`. After accomplishing your reult, assign `rlg_time` this value before the limit(end of access point) of that local variable `local`. And now you can successfully return `rlg_time`. By the way it is not at all associated with Java only!

Comment: You have taught me a great lesson. Thanks the code has worked well by following your advice.

Comment: @user3678356-It is a real pleasure for me to satisfy you with my proper explanation over the question. Feel free to ask any doubt you wish. I am myself on the learning stage!

Answer (score 0):

Its extremely difficult to read your code. Please indent your code properly. Anyways If there are no other errors ,just return type problem then change your code to this:-

```
import com.google.common.collect.ObjectArrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;
import java.util.regex.*;


public class ArrayReturnSurTime {

    public static float[] ranisurtime(String sur36) { 


        int count1=0;
        int count2=0;
        int total_full_sur=0;
        float word_time= 0.25f;
        float full_sur_time=0.0f;
        float kan_sur_time=0.0f;
        float kun_sur_time=0.0f;
        float[] rlg_time=null;

        String word=sur36; 
        String modifyword=null;String after =null;String rl=null;

        char[] c = word.toCharArray();
        int m=c.length; 
        for(int i= 0; i<c.length; i++){
            count1++; 
            if(c[i]==']'){count2++;} 
            total_full_sur= count1-2*count2; 
            full_sur_time=word_time/total_full_sur;
            kan_sur_time = (float) (full_sur_time*0.1);
            kun_sur_time = (float) (full_sur_time*0.9);
        }
        for(int p=0; p<word.length(); p++){  
            char  a =  word.charAt(p);
            if( Character.toString(a).equals("]")) {
                int j = p-1;int k = p+1;char b =   word.charAt(j);char d =   word.charAt(k);
                modifyword= word.replace( Character.valueOf(b).toString(), ".");
                after=  modifyword.replace( Character.valueOf(d).toString(), ",");

                rl = after;

                String[] tmp_rl= rl.split ("(?!^)");
                rlg_time= new float[tmp_rl.length]; //changed here

                for(int x=0; x<rl.length(); x++){

                    switch (tmp_rl[x]) {
                    case ".":
                        rlg_time[x]=kan_sur_time;
                        break;  
                    case ",":
                        rlg_time[x]=kun_sur_time;
                        break;
                    case "]":
                        rlg_time[x]=(float)0.001;
                        break;
                    default:
                        rlg_time[x]=full_sur_time;
                        break;
                    }

                }

            }//First closing bracket to be crossed by 'return rlg_time'.
        } // Second  closing bracket to be crossed by  'return rlg_time'.
        return rlg_time;//It is the right place at which 'return rlg_time'. statement can do right, but how to manipulate to reach here.
    }  

    public static void main( String[] args )
    { 

        String sur36="srg]mp";

        float[] A  =    ranisurtime(sur36);

        for(int i=0; i<A.length; i++){
            System.out.print(A[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I have not tried this but it should work. You are initializing you FLoat[] array rlg_time in if statment. Hence as soon as your if statement ends the variable will be deallocated. Moved the declaration of variable outside of if statement.

Comment: The real problem is that when I shift the return here the compiler does not find the variable 'rgl_time' to return.

Comment: It will now, see the code, i have moved the declaration of rgl_time

Answer (score 0):

First, look at the rewrite of the computation of the times:

```
for(int i= 0; i<word.length(); i++){
    if(word.charAt(i)==']'){count2++;}
}
total_full_sur= word.length() - 2*count2;
full_sur_time=word_time/total_full_sur;
kan_sur_time = (float) (full_sur_time*0.1);
kun_sur_time = (float) (full_sur_time*0.9);
```

Apart from eliminating useless complications, note *that you do not include computations in a loop that depend on the loop having been completed*.

If you think about the next loop in the same way, it'll solve your problem.